# Angular How to download a file of size 1GB

Tags: angular

I was googling for the solution of downloading a big file - 1GB - in an Angular application and still haven't found a proper approach. 
I saw a lot of posts here, but most of them lead to file-saver package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) which has limitations on the downloaded file size.

My question would be - are there any means to download a file of that size in angular? or file-saver is the only choice?
In my application, the back-end GET rest point returns a blob and I need to consume it and save to file.
Thank you in advance!